# Strange console.log behaviour on keypress

Tags: console, keypress

If the `keyPressed` event is 27 by pressing 'esc' it will print the `console.log("ESCY");` as many times as the `loopcnt` var, all at once

```
    loopcnt = 0;
var fps = 22;
var interval = 1000 / fps;

function draw()
{
    setTimeout(function() 
    {

        if (willAnimate)
        {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            console.log("Framecnt: "+ loopcnt);
            loopcnt++;

        }

        IndexJSON.each(function(key, value){ IndexOBJECT[key].render(); });

        $(window).delegate('body', 'keydown', function(event){
            keyPressed = event.which;
            if (keyPressed == 27)
            {
                willAnimate = false;
                console.log("ESCY");
            }           
        }); 
    }, interval);
};

willAnimate = true;
draw();
```

If you ask me, it doesn't make logical sense...

It's as if it's buffering all the `console.log`s, until the `if` statement is true..

Any idea why this happens?

(And another question: I tried cancelling the `setTimeout` function with `return`, but it won't terminate the function, probably because `return` will only return from the if statement, but is there a way to externally terminate the function?)

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently when I move the .delegate outside the setTimeout(); It won't trigger the if statement multiple times.

And, I'm realizing now, that I'm binding the key every time the loop loops, thus when I press the key it will trigger all the bindings..

Pretty obvious now that I think about it...